# CocoaPods adding duplicate frameworks to Tests project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, shared-libraries, cocoapods

I've got a workspace with a single project (MyProject) and three targets (MyProject, MyProjectTests, and MyProjectPlugin). I have a Podfile set up for it with three dependencies. The first two should be linked to all three targets, but the third (OCMock) should only be linked to my Tests target. This is my Podfile:

```
platform :osx, '10.8'

pod 'objective-zip', :podspec => 'Podspecs/objective-zip.podspec'
link_with 'MyProject', 'MyProjectPlugin', 'MyProjectTests'

pod 'Unrar4iOS', :path => '../Unrar4iOS'
link_with 'MyProject', 'MyProjectPlugin', 'MyProjectTests'

target : MyProjectTests do
    pod 'OCMock', '~> 2.2.3'
end
```

What I expect to happen is for `libPods.a` to only have `objective-zip` and `Unrar4iOS` contained in it, and for `libPods-MyProjectTests.a` to be a superset, with those two, and `OCMock`. This is, in fact, the case, which I verified by looking at the targets set up in Pods.xcodeproj. So the correct way to link these frameworks to my projects is for the main an plugin projects to use `libPods.a` and for the tests project to use `libPods-MyProjectTests.a`. When I configure the projects this way, everything compiles and runs well.

Here's the problem. Whenever I `pod update` with a new dependency, `libPods.a` gets linked to MyProjectTests on top of `libPods-MyProjectTests.a`, which results in compiler errors (`ld` reports duplicate symbols, as expected).

Is this a CocoaPods bug, or do I need to update my Podfile. This is a nuisance when developing locally, but will be a major problem when I configure an automated build that will `pod install` every time (since I don't, and don't intend to, commit the Pods directory).

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for a proper answer (either what I'm doing wrong, or that there's a bug in CocoaPods), but I came up with this workaround. I wrapped `pod install` with a Ruby script that uses Xcodeproj to remove the redundant library from my Tests project:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'

gem 'xcodeproj'
require 'xcodeproj'

puts `pod install`

puts 'Removing extra linked library'
main_project = Xcodeproj::Project.open('Comickaze.xcodeproj')
tests_target = main_project.targets.find{|target| target.name == 'ComickazeTests'}

framework_to_remove = tests_target.frameworks_build_phase.files.find{|file| file.display_name == 'libPods.a'}
tests_target.frameworks_build_phase.remove_file_reference(framework_to_remove.file_ref)

main_project.save
```

I will not accept this answer, because there has to be a better way.